# Sprite Kit not working in 64bit simulator

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Using SpriteKit for the first time to animate. Animating a set of bear walking images - very basic. However while the app runs well in 32 bit mode simulator, it is garbled when run in 64 bit simulator.

Here is the ViewController -

// CPViewController.h

```
@interface CPViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

// CPViewController.m

```
@implementation CPViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    SKScene * scene = [CPMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

@end
```

// CPMyScene.h

```
@interface CPMyScene : SKScene

@end
```

// CPMyScene.m

```
@implementation CPMyScene {
    SKSpriteNode *_bear;
    NSArray *_bearWalkingFrames;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
        NSMutableArray *bearWalkingFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        SKTextureAtlas *bearAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"BearImages"];
        NSUInteger frameCount = bearAtlas.textureNames.count;
        for (int i=1 ; i<=frameCount ; i++) {
            NSString *frameImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear%d",i];
            SKTexture *frameImage = [bearAtlas textureNamed:frameImageName];
            [bearWalkingFrames addObject:frameImage];
        }
        _bearWalkingFrames = bearWalkingFrames;
        SKTexture *firstFrame = _bearWalkingFrames[0];
        _bear = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:firstFrame];
        _bear.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        [self addChild:_bear];
        [self startWalkingTheBear];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) startWalkingTheBear {
    [_bear runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:_bearWalkingFrames timePerFrame:0.1f resize:NO restore:YES]] withKey:@"WalkingBear"];
}

@end
```

The images are 233 x 145 px.

Here is a video in simulator in 32 bit mode -

http://youtu.be/fqJzS-XN0tk

Here is a video in simulator in 64 bit mode (DOES NOT WORK - IMAGE BOUNDARIES WRONG or something) -

http://youtu.be/Kby9aP4gSzg

**References:**

http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases - the code is mostly from here except tailored for iPhone and iPad instead of just iPad.

Comment: I had a similar issue with SpriteKit not working on 64bit/iPhone5S. The SKScene just appeared as a grey screen. Turned out making the @property 'strong' solved the problem!

Comment: Where do you put it @DavidDouglas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had to add @2x images to the image atlas folder. The @2x images are not twice the size of non @2x images, but just a copy of the non @2x images and just renamed with @2x. This is really funny though.